# Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon

Tags: samba, smb

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu active directory domain controller with Samba. I installed Samba, and configured it. When I start the smbd.service, it fails by saying "Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with the error code."

`Feb 08 15:52:38 samba-01.lab.dev systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Feb 08 15:52:38 samba-01.lab.dev smbd[8634]: [2020/02/08 15:52:38.255684,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1803(main)
Feb 08 15:52:38 samba-01.lab.dev smbd[8634]:   server role = 'active directory domain controller' not compatible with running smbd standalone.
Feb 08 15:52:38 samba-01.lab.dev smbd[8634]:   You should start 'samba' instead, and it will control starting smbd if required
Feb 08 15:52:38 samba-01.lab.dev systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 08 15:52:38 samba-01.lab.dev systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 15:52:38 samba-01.lab.dev systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.`

Any suggestions on how I can get it working?

Comment: Did you try starting 'samba' instead?

Comment: Yes, I did @OrganicMarble.